# C# Saving Objects

Tags: c#, database, file, save

I want to be able to save several objects which are linked each other. Idea is to have a Client object, Project object, Work object which will interfere each other. All data within will be as string and int. Everything will be joined in Record Object in which I will choose values from mentions object plus adding new entries.
What would be the best way to save all into a file - serialization? Is it possible to do it with some kind of data base? So far it is recorded in Excel table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Serialization is fast and compact way to do it, but with linq you have XML and XML serialization which is closer to what you are looking for : 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx

To go further Linq was created to simplify database queries so by default you will be able to access any ODBC compatible database (sqLite MySQL etc...)

FYI : You can Edit XML and XML scheme with Excel (if that's the kind of things your're into)